# Azure DevOps: Populating secure file references with job matrix variables

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, devops

For context, I am trying to use an Azure build pipeline to build multiple flavors of an Android app. Each flavor has its own separate signing keystore, and all of those keystores are stored in my 'secure files' in the library.

However, when I try to dereference the $(Keystore) variable during the 'android signing' task, it doesn't seem to recognize that that is a variable that exists, and tries instead to locate a file called '$(Keystore)'

Am I doing something wrong here? This seems like it should work.

A sanitized example looks like this:

```
# Android
# Build your Android project with Gradle.
# Add steps that test, sign, and distribute the APK, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/android

trigger:
- feat/ci-setup

pool:
  vmImage: 'macos-latest'

variables:
  ${{ if startsWith(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/feat/') }}: 
    Branch_Type: 'feature'
  ${{ if startsWith(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/hotfix/') }}: 
    Branch_Type: 'hotfix'
  ${{ if startsWith(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release/') }}: 
    Branch_Type: 'release'
  ${{ if eq(variables['Branch_Type'], 'release') }}: 
    Configuration: 'release'
    ConfigurationCC: 'Release'
  ${{ if ne(variables['Branch_Type'], 'release') }}: 
    Configuration: 'debug'
    ConfigurationCC: 'Debug'

jobs:
- job: Build
  variables:
  - group: android_keystores
  strategy:
    maxParallel: 2
    matrix:
      Flavor_1:
        AppFlavor: '1'
        AppFlavorCC: '1'
        Keystore: 'flavor1.keystore'
        KeyAlias: 'flavor1'
        KeystorePass: '$(flavor1_storepass)'
        KeyPass: '$(flavor1_keypass)'
      Flavor_2:
        AppFlavor: '2'
        AppFlavorCC: '2'
        Keystore: 'flavor2.keystore'
        KeyAlias: 'flavor2'
        KeystorePass: '$(flavor2_storepass)'
        KeyPass: '$(flavor2_keypass)'

  steps:
  - task: Gradle@2
    inputs:
      workingDirectory: ''
      gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
      gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
      publishJUnitResults: false
      tasks: 'assemble$(AppFlavorCC)$(ConfigurationCC)'

  - task: AndroidSigning@3
    displayName: Signing .apk
    inputs:
      apkFiles: 'app/build/outputs/apk/$(AppFlavor)/$(Configuration)/*.apk'
      apksign: true
      apksignerKeystoreFile: '$(Keystore)'
      apksignerKeystorePassword: '$(KeystorePass)'
      apksignerKeystoreAlias: '$(KeyAlias)'
      apksignerKeyPassword: '$(KeyPass)'
      zipalign: true

  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: Move APK to Artifact Folder
    continueOnError: true
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        mv \
        app/build/outputs/apk/$(AppFlavor)/$(Configuration)/*.apk \
        $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(ArtifactName)/

  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    displayName: Publish Build Artifacts
    inputs:
      PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      ArtifactName: 'Blueprint-Build'
      publishLocation: 'Container'
```

But when the pipeline runs I am told this:

```
There was a resource authorization issue: "The pipeline is not valid. Job Build: Step AndroidSigning input keystoreFile references secure file $(Keystore) which could not be found. The secure file does not exist or has not been authorized for use. For authorization details, refer to https://aka.ms/yamlauthz."
```

Comment: Yes, I accepted your answer below since, even though I went a different route, it looks like that would have solved my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Azure DevOps: Populating secure file references with job matrix variables

This is a limitation from the task itself.

When we test it with Classic mode, we could find out that the value of the option **Keystore file** could not be entered manually, we could only select a certain file through the drop-down menu:

[image]

That the reason why it doesn't seem to recognize that that is a variable that exists, and tries instead to locate a file called '`$(Keystore)`'.

**To resolve this issue**, you could change the task version from `3` to `1`, which supports manual input:

[image]

And as another solution, you could also use the command line to sign the *.apk:

[Android apk signing: sign an unsigned apk using command line](https://medium.com/modulotech/how-to-sign-an-unsigned-apk-using-command-line-636a056373a0)

Comment: That's a good tip on changing the task version, I may try that.
The workaround I opted for was to just do the signing as part of the release pipeline instead, since I have to have separate jobs for each flavor anyway during release.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the step to download the Secure File. Unlike variable groups, you need to explicitly download them to have access via the secure file name.

You'll want to add something similar to the example task below to your steps to pull the secure file. Then, you'll access your secure file via **NAME_PARAMETER.secureFilePath**:

```
          - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
            displayName: "Download Keyfile 1"
            name: "YOUR_SECUREFILE_NAME"
            inputs:
                secureFile: keyfile1
          - task: AndroidSigning@3
            displayName: Signing .apk
            inputs:
                apkFiles: 'app/build/outputs/apk/$(AppFlavor)/$(Configuration)/*.apk'
                apksign: true
                apksignerKeystoreFile: '$(YOUR_SECUREFILE_NAME.secureFilePath)'
                apksignerKeystorePassword: '$(KeystorePass)'
                apksignerKeystoreAlias: '$(KeyAlias)'
                apksignerKeyPassword: '$(KeyPass)'
                zipalign: true
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try adding the DownloadSecureFile task, but based on the documentation for the Android Signing task, it seems like it checks your library directly.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/android-signing?view=azure-devops

I suspect the issue comes from it trying to trigger the file download prior to the matrix parameters actually being parsed, but I'll report my results here. I could be wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately the issue with the DownloadSecureFile task is the same as the issue with the AndroidSigning task, when I reference the Keyfile as a variable. 
```
The pipeline is not valid. Job Blueprint_Build: Step Signing_Keystore input secureFile references secure file $(Keystore) which could not be found.
```
I'm trying to avoid having to download _every_ keystore for each instance of the pipeline job, but if I can't use a strategy matrix value for this I'll have to have a task for each flavor, which defeats the purpose of using strategies. Which would suck.

Comment: That's a bummer, sorry the solution didn't work out. Offhand, the only other thing I can think of is if the keyfile isn't authorized for use within the pipeline. But, in that case, you're typically prompted to grant access within the pipeline itself before it runs.

Comment: hmm. Lame. I guess I'll have to do all the builds then have individual tasks to sign them all.
Thanks for your help, in any case.